# VBA WinHttp no mapping character

Tags: vba, winhttp, winhttprequest

Here is the source of a function I use get HTML code for further proccessing:

```
Public Function DownloadTextFile(url As String) As String
    Dim oHTTP As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

    Set oHTTP = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    oHTTP.Open Method:="GET", url:=url, async:=False
    oHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    'oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; "
    oHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8"
    oHTTP.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = True
    oHTTP.send

    Dim success As Boolean
    success = oHTTP.waitForResponse()
    If Not success Then
        Debug.Print "DOWNLOAD FAILED!"
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim responseText As String
    Debug.Print oHTTP.responseText

    responseText = oHTTP.responseText
    'Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("c:\testfile.txt", True, False)
    'Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("c:\testfile.txt", True, True)
    'a.WriteLine oHTTP.responseText
    'a.Close

    Set oHTTP = Nothing

    DownloadTextFile = responseText
End Function
```

It works for most pages, but for some pages the `responseText` is `No Mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page`.

Here is an example of web page for which the `responseText` is `No Mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page`

http://bzp0.portal.uzp.gov.pl/index.php?ogloszenie=browser&action=search&rodzajzamowienia=B&rodzajogloszenia=1&aktualne=1&datapublikacji_rodzaj=5&iloscwynikownastronie=20&offset=20

and here is a suspicious character that can't be encoded (screenshot from google chrome):

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/585/errsource.png/

From time to time on same website but for different search result this function does not generate error, but then, the HTML source in immidiate window is like `?????? ...`

Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

Solution that worked for me:

```
responseText = VBA.Strings.StrConv(oHTTP.ResponseBody, vbUnicode)
```

Note the use of ResponseBody instead of ResponseText

Answer (score 1):

Try to use StrConv:

```
DownloadTextFile = VBA.Strings.StrConv(responseText, vbUnicode)
```

vbUnicode: Converts the string to Unicode using the default code page of the system. (Not available on the Macintosh.)

Comment: Hi Daniel. I have check your suggestion and it provides some progress on problem solution.

Comment: For couple of web pages with the character from screen shot, debuger marks "responseText = oHTTP.responseText" part of the code with, and oHTTP.responseText contains "No mapping character..."

Comment: And did you try: responseText = StrConv(oHTTP.responseText,vbUnicode) ?